# SP.Runtime.Js doesn't get loaded for Some pages and adding the SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.Runtime.js', someFunction()); also doesn't help;

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

The issue is only in IE. The same code runs fine in other browsers.

I have a below code which runs in all other pages of my share point Portal site and breaks only on a Page where i could figure out the issue is "Sp.js and Sp.Runtime.Js" are not get loaded though we never have to load them explicitly as they are already being refereed in master page .
the code break at the line where i am calling:
ClientContext = new Sp.ClientContext("SomeUrl");

Error:

> Object doesn't support property or method
>   'set_formDigestHandlingEnabled'

Also loading it Explicitly breaking the other page functionality.

If any one have any suggestions ..please reply as soon as possible.

```
InforRegion: function () {
            var clientContext, clientContext2, site, web, listConfig, camlConfig, camlQueryConfig, userInfo;
            var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
            var currentUserID = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
            try {
                var preferredRegion = CC3Portal.Utilities.Cache.GetItem('preferredRegion');
                console.log("GetItem cached preferredRegion: " + preferredRegion);
                if (preferredRegion == null) {

                    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("SomeURL");
                    //clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                    site = clientContext.get_site();
                    web = site.get_rootWeb();
                    listConfig = web.get_lists().getByTitle(CC3Portal.Utilities.Constants.userInfoList);
                    camlConfig = new SP.CamlQuery();
                    camlQueryConfig = "<View>" + "<ViewFields>" + "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>" + "<FieldRef Name='CCPreferredRegionNewsUpdated'/>" +
                     "<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/>" + "<FieldRef Name='ID'/>" + "<FieldRef Name='CCRegion'/>" + "</ViewFields>" + "<Query>" +
                     "<Where>" + "<Eq>" + "<FieldRef Name='CCWWID' LookupId='True'/>" + "<Value Type='Lookup'>" + currentUserID + "</Value>" +
                     "</Eq>" + "</Where>" + "</Query>" + "</View>";
                    camlConfig.set_viewXml(camlQueryConfig);
                    userInfo = listConfig.getItems(camlConfig);
                    clientContext.load(userInfo);
                    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Succeeded, ItemFailed);
                }
```